# A shell script problem for comparing difference between two files. [Linux]

Tags: linux, shell

Now my program generates two data files. a.txt and b.txt
Take a.txt as an example, it's content just like this:

```
0,0
0,1
1,0
-3,1
1,-2
1,3
......
```

b.txt is similar with a.txt.

Now, I hope to find out difference lines count.
In other words, for example, if b.txt like this:

```
0,0
1,1
1,2
-3,1
1,-2
1,3
......
```

a shell script output 2 as the 2nd and the 3rd lines are different with one number different.  How to do this???

I try diff command, however, I cannot get what I want...

Need your kind help..Thanks.

**Addition:**
There are about 10,000 - 100,000 rows for each files.  Of course, they have same no. of rows at each time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
diff a.txt b.txt | grep "<" | wc -l
```

Comment: Welcome! Actually, I think you need "<" instead of "---". I've made a correction in the answer.

Answer (score 3):

Faced the same problem a while back. What you need is diffstat. Diffstat is part of the GNU diff package and can summarizes diff results:

> **SYNOPSIS**
>
> diffstat reads the output of diff and
>   displays a histogram of the
>   insertions, deletions, and
>   modifications per-file. It is useful
>   for reviewing large, complex patch
>   files.

You can also process the output of diffstat to get summarized results:

diff -u FileA.txt FileB.txt | diffstat -f0 | grep -v files | awk '{ print $3 }'

Where -u is obligatory. You can explore diffstat documentation for options.

Answer (score 1):

`diff` seems to be exactly what you want.

```
#> diff a.txt b.txt
2,3c2,3
< 0,1
< 1,0
---
> 1,1
> 1,2
```

Is there something more specific you were looking for?

Comment: when I type as you said, I got this message,
grep: unrecognized option '---',

Answer (score 1):

diff may move chunks within a file which is not what you want I think.
Here's an alternative:

```
join -t'\0' -v2 <(cat -n a.txt) <(cat -n b.txt) | wc -l
```